# Spring Security: How to get the automatically rendered login page code?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Is it possible to get the automatically rendered login code from a Spring Security Project?

The new Spring Project examples are not with any XML or JSP files. I used the Spring framework in the past and I remember you need to configure a XML file and you had JSP data for html.

Now i want to make a Spring MVC Login page for LDAP authentication.
But the examples are without any XML and JSP files. Is it possible to get them to have full controll of the code?

Some links:

- I use the [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/#wsca)
- [Authenticating a User with LDAP](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)

This is the method that generates the login form:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
}
```

I just want to create the login form by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `security:form-login login-page` tag in your spring security configuration xml file. It will automatically redirect your application to login page.

**REMEBER:** *to configure these url's in your Controller.*

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessDenied"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginFail"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout"
            access="permitAll" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <security:access-denied-handler
            error-page="/accessDenied" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/home" always-use-default-target="true"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginFail" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>
```

This one is the best [reference tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892822/Spring-security-in-java) on spring security, I have came across. Please try to configure your application according to this and If you want both configurations(*JAVA/XML*) [REFER THIS](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/).

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks! so i must not divine a login.jsp? what if i want to have the login integrate in a page?

Comment: Just follow the steps given in MKYONG example. There should be a login file but it's form action should be a spring security attribute "<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />".

Comment: okay, you know that the mkyong example is not working? at least the comments below say that.

Comment: No its working i have tried it once, but I recommend, try to configure it according to your need that will help you to understand it better.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is to supply the url of the custom form you have created,

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/myApp/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()                                    
            .permitAll();
}
```

and return the jsp of the login form by a controller, e.g

```
@RequestMapping("/myApp/login")
public String myLoginForm() {
    return "myLoginForm";
}
```

Don't forget to set the action attribute of the login form as "/login", if you are using spring-security-4